# Yarn workspaces with babel, ts, etc?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

Is there a "correct" way to have globally available scripts w/ yarn workspaces?

Let's take typescript as an example.  If I install it at the root level using `yarn add -W typescript` it's not available in any of my workspaces:

```sh
child-workspace$ yarn tsc
yarn run v1.22.10
error Command "tsc" not found.
```

Now I can install `tsc` into every workspace, along with babel, jest, etc etc etc, but that's awfully redundant.  I'm looking for a way to have tools at the global level that are used by each of the workspaces.

Even better, if possible, would be if there were a way to have a "build" workspace and have all the scripts from that globally available so they can be cleanly separated from the workspace root.